# using csh alises with single quote or double quotes

Tags: linux, csh

I am trying to use the following alias with multiple " and ' while the syntax is not clear to me.
Should I use backslash before every candidate?

in summary, how do I make it work? :)

```
alias <command> 'printenv |egrep -w "word1|word2" | perl -nae 'print "command\n;' > file'
```

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

ok...found it

```
alias before_fabrics_env 'printenv | egrep -w "word1|word2" | perl -nae ' " ' " 'print "command\n" ' " ' " ' > file'
```